# MySQL Server gone away in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1:30", "root", "");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->
        connect_error;
    exit("..............");
}
```

This code executes a long time and in the end it says `MySQL Server has gone away`.

`Apache Port` is `30`

`MySQL server` port is `3306`

Using `Microsoft Windows 8.1`

Comment: `mysqli("127.0.0.1:30", "root", "");` connects to the apache port, not the MySQL port it should be connecting to.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson But standard HTTP port is 80, maybe he changed the standard MySQL port?

Comment: @user4035 The question states that MySQL is on port 3306.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson See it now, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use this

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
```

> mysqli.default_port=3306

this will connect by default through 3306 port.

check  [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Comment: I tried this one too. but it is giving me following error
`Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ..............`

Comment: Please note that
server is accessible as : `127.0.0.1:30` in browser

Comment: have you checked your firewall if the port is closed?

Comment: try close firewall and see. it maybe caused by it. if so , then add exception to that port.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, it was working fine for me almost a week ago, but now it is behaving like that

Comment: Increase your `wait_timeout` and `net_read_timeout` to something bigger than 180sec (3mins) like 3600sec if there are some queries that takes longer or if you are getting results sets that are really big.

Comment: I didn't understand why to increase `time` and packet `size` as I'm not executing anything,
I'm just trying to connect it to `localhost` and just a single `connection_query` is running there, **nothing else**

Though I'm trying this too.

Comment: this i said it in case when you executing and its limited so it will go away also as its limited when you have long queries.If you dont execute anything , then forget about this suggestion.